# Is there a way to prevent the contents of my window from "moving" when i resize the window in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, viewport, glfw, opengl-3

I would like my window contents to stay centered when my window resizes. OpenGL (or GLFW) - I'm not sure which - does give this desired effect when resizing horizontally, however when i resize the window vertically the window appears to show the more of the bottom of the cube. I expected it to cut off the cube like when resizing horizontally,

This is the horizontal resize
[image: Horizontal Resize]

And this is the vertical resize
[image: Vertical Resize]

Note: I do not make any `glViewPort()`  otherwise the window contents would adjust to the new width and height.

Is there any way to change this behaviour? This question may be related but i don't believe that is solves my problem. [How to keep the OpenGL viewport in an SDL window stationary ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474412/how-to-keep-the-opengl-viewport-in-an-sdl-window-stationary-when-a-window-is-res)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "../includes/Shader.h"
#include "../includes/Texture.h"
#include "../includes/glm/glm.hpp"


const int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height);

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

int main() {

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window! " << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW! " << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    float vertices[] = {
            ...
    };

    unsigned int VAO, VBO;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, (GLvoid *) nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, (GLvoid *) (sizeof(float) * 3));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    Texture texture1("../images/container.jpg");
    Texture texture2("../images/awesomeface.png");

    Shader shader("../shaders/shader.vs", "../shaders/shader.fs");

    shader.use();
    shader.setUniform1i("texture1", 0);
    shader.setUniform1i("texture2", 1);


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        processInput(window);

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        texture1.bind(0);
        texture2.bind(1);

        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        model = glm::rotate(model, (float) glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
        projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 800.0f/600.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        shader.setUniformMat4("model", model);
        shader.setUniformMat4("view", view);
        shader.setUniformMat4("projection", projection);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height) {
    //glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window) {
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: OpenGL _already_ does what you want. This _can_ work  only for 2 of the 4 borders, and it does so on the right and top one - which is a result of OpenGL using the bottom left as the origin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply do you know of any way to account for the bottom and left side.

Comment: Well, you can adjust the viewport and compensate for it by basically cropping the image via a change of the projection matrix, which boils down to pre-multiplying some scane and translation. While this is not exactly what you're looking for, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28201492/2327517) I gave some details about the required math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: I do not make any glViewPort() otherwise the window contents would adjust to the new width and height.

This is the problem. You need to adjust the viewport. Adjust the field of view depending on the viewport:

```cpp
const float defaultHeight = 600.0f;
const float defaultFov = glm::radians(45.0f);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

    // [...]

    int vpSize[2];
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &vpSize[0], &vpSize[1]);
    glViewport(0, 0, vpSize[0], vpSize[1]);

    float aspect = (float)vpSize[0] / (float)vpSize[1];
    float fov = asin(sin(defaultFov / 2.0f) * vpSize[1] / defaultHeight) * 2.0f;
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(fov, aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    // [...]
}
```